# Mipmap launcher icon in Oreo not working

Tags: android, icons, launcher, android-8.0-oreo, android-mipmap

As a rule of thumb launcher icon are under the mipmap res folder, but now with Oreo update it doesn't work, I get the default android icon instead of my launcher icon.

Looks like I have to put foreground and background asset under all drawable combinations (mdpi, hdpi...) and then have a mipmap-any-dpi res folder that have an xml with background and foreground linked to the drawable assets for the adaptive launcher icon.

So looks like I am mixing drawable and mipmap folders for launcher icons.

I also tried with roundIcon but doesnt work.

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Can anyone help?